# By what time should I be completely finished cleaning my home and searching for chametz?

Tags: halacha, minhag, passover, chametz-leaven

My community's calendar says to eat Chametz until 11:06AM, and to burn Chametz by 12:12PM, and to light candles at 7:36PM. Does this mean that I need to be completely finished with kashering my home, and have all chametz out by 12:12PM? If I were to encounter chametz that was not seen prior to 12:12PM, could I still remove it after 12:12PM?

Also, if the kashering of an oven or dishes hadn't quite reached the 24-hour mark since the physical kashering, would the appliance or dishes be considered treif and chametz by 12:12PM?

Comment: Re "24-hour mark since the physical kashering": I think you may have misunderstood something. Depending on what typing of kashering is being done (and to what), you may need to wait a day *before* kashering. I've never heard of having to wait *after* kashering (except that the thing kashered often has to be cooled down before use). But please consult your rabbi.

Comment: Thank you for all the great comments. I think I definitely did a misread of the Conservative guide regarding the 24-hour period. Chag Kasher v’Sameach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that I need to be completely finished with kashering my
>   home, and have all chametz out by 12:12PM?

You need to be finished kashering by Noon, which will be about an hour after you have to be done with burning your Chametz.

You need to have all chametz sold or destroyed by 12:12PM.

> If I were to encounter chametz that was not seen prior to 12:12PM,
>   could I still remove it after 12:12PM?

Chametz found after 12:12PM must be destroyed **immediately**. Preferably by fire. Do not eat it!

> Also, if the kashering of an oven or dishes hadn't quite reached the
>   24-hour mark since the physical kashering, would the appliance or
>   dishes be considered treif and chametz by 12:12PM?

The 24-hour period is needed **before** kashering in boiling water. Kashering in boiling water after Noon on Erev Pessach, or during Pessach would require Rabbinic guidance, if it's at all possible.

Kashering by fire is allowed after Noon.

The preferred route is to make sure everything is kashered before Noon; thus stop using it before Noon the day before.

Dishes not kashered are Chametz and cannot be used during Pessach. They are not Treif, and can be used after Pessach without further ado if they were clean.

All answers based in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 116.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in guides such as the OU guide and the shulchan Aruch (Siman 434) and Chayei Adam Klal 119 Seif 29, if you find chametz after the time, it should be destroyed immediately. If it is found on Yom Tov, then it is to be covered (because it is muktzah) and destroyed immediately after Yom Tov. I am not sure what you mean by 'kashering your home' as you should have found and removed all chametz by the bedikah the night before. If you mean that you need to wait 24 hours before kashering the sink, then as long as you get it done before you need to use it for Pesach, then you should be OK. Since kashering the oven is usually done by libun (burning - see the OU guide), which is nowadays normally done using the self clean feature of the oven, you do  not (in that normal case) have to wait for 24 hours after the last use before doing it.

Dishes are not normally able to be kashered (because they are china), which is why we have Pesach dishes. I do not understand what you mean by "24 hour mark since the physical kashering" because once something is kosher for Pesach, you do not have to wait before using it.

Actually, if you are going to stop eating or using the Chametz earlier than the last minute, you should do the burning and the bitul (nullification) as soon as you can. It is better as a practical matter not to wait until the last minute to do so. After all, what if your watch is slow.